# Can anyone explain me the VBA DB connection string?

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am newbie to VBA. Can any one help to understand below DB connection string.

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Tracker;Data Source=GCHDB01;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"
```

Also what is the table name in this. Some piece of code below.

```
objMyConn.Open
Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = "exec SGD_RPT_ACTIVITY_LEDGER " & "'" & Trim(inTACStartDate) & "', " & "'" & Trim(inTACEndDate) & "'"
```

Comment: Connection string varies from a db to other. https://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/

Comment: Thanks Trimax. I went through the link you provided but there is no where mentioned about the attributes of the Connection string...

Comment: Connection string: See link posted by Trimax. 
There's not table name in your example - the command says "exec Something" --> You're executing a stored procedure in the database, so you'll have to check there.

Answer (score 0):

As I've previously commented, the attributes varies from a provider from other.
There is an example of my own Oracle 11 DB, named "GESTORES":

```
Dim SQL_String As String
Dim dbConnectStr As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim recordCount As Long
dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=" & "GESTORES; User Id=empresa2" & "; Password=" & "empresa2"
```

The attributes are explaining by themselves.